# Java - How to add separated numbers

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
String happyNumber = input.nextLine();

int happyNum = Integer.parseInt(happyNumber);
happyNum *= happyNum;

int answer = 0;  
for (char ch : Integer.toString(happyNum).toCharArray()) {
    int digit = ch - '0';
    answer = digit * digit;
    System.out.print(answer);
}
```

For example:

> Enter a number:7
>
> The output is:
> 16
> 81

Now guys, I want to add 16 and 81. The sum will be 97. I have tried research and all but still, I can't solve this simple problem.

Comment: What research did you try?

Comment: I did search on how to add separated numbers but their ploblems was different with mine.

Comment: Don't tell us you did it, show us.

Comment: I tried answer=answer+answer but it's wrong. Since variable answer was divided into 2numbers 16 and 81.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sum to keep track of your total =)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
String happyNumber = input.nextLine();

int happyNum = Integer.parseInt(happyNumber);
happyNum *= happyNum;


int answer = 0;
int sum = 0; //NEW
for (char ch : Integer.toString(happyNum).toCharArray()) {
    int digit = ch - '0';
    answer = digit * digit;
    sum = sum + answer;//NEW
    System.out.print(answer);

}
System.out.print("Sum: " + sum);//NEW
```

Try and understand the change of code. I added //NEW to each line I added

Comment: Got it sir! Thanks for your help. It's an additional information since i am new to Java.